# virtual environment's architecture made by pipenv become intel chip on apple mac m1

Tags: python, virtualenv, apple-m1

[image]

I'm struggling with using python on mac m1, and I found that there's an issue on `pipenv` for making virtual environment with correct architecture. As you can see on the above picture, when I open the terminal with aram64 architecture and make virtual environment using `pipenv`, the architecture becomes i386. I'm not sure if this causes a big problem, it blocked me to use some of 3rd party packages such as `numpy` and `pandas`, although I failed to reproduce the error. (As I remember, it showed an error message like `mach-o: but wrong architecture`.) The version of `pipenv` I'm using is 2021.5.29.

```
> arch
arm64

> pipenv --python 3.8
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/seewoolee/development/tmp/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.8.9) to create virtualenv...
⠦ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.8.9.final.0-64 in 388ms
  creator CPython3macOsFramework(dest=/Users/seewoolee/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-miv_sugU, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/seewoolee/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.2.4, setuptools==58.1.0, wheel==0.37.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /Users/seewoolee/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-miv_sugU
Creating a Pipfile for this project...

> pipenv shell

Launching subshell in virtual environment...
. /Users/seewoolee/.local/share/virtualenvs/tmp-miv_sugU/bin/activate

> arch
i386
```

Comment: What is the architecture of the pipenv executable itself?  `file` will tell you?  If it is intel, I believe that pipenv will run under rosetta 2 and thus the arch it sees is intel. And it will try to install intel pythons. This can happen if you migrated from an intel mac (for example).  Or if you already had a py 3.8 intel version and migrated that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem, and @Beel's comment gave me the clue that I needed to solve it. In my case, `pipenv` was referencing a version of `python` that was built for `x86_64`. Specifically:

```
$ which pipenv
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pipenv
$ file /opt/anaconda3/bin/python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

This happened when I installed Anaconda and it put itself at the front of my `PATH`. After adjusting my path to resolve to the version of Pipenv I had installed, `pipenv shell` does not switch the `arch` as a side-effect, and I was able to install the correct versions of `numpy`, `psutil`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you migrated from an intel mac to an m1, already installed executables (such as `pipenv` or the python 3.8.9 installation) could be satisfied by the already installed intel executables.

If you did not migrate, keep in mind that any installer (brew, pip, pipenv, or VS Code) that is installed as intel will run under Rosetta 2, where the arch will be intel.  Anything they attempt to install will also be intel.  So be sure your installers are the architecture you want (intel or arm).  For some situations, you may want both and select one or the other via PATH settings.

That said, be aware that older versions of python or modules may not be available for M1's.  Installers attempting to install from source may fail if the older source Makefiles don't know what to do for an arm arch.

Answer (score 0):

I think M1 chip does not have good support from pipenv/python packages, may be this can help you to install panda package and can be example of approach for another packages too:

https://megah-f.medium.com/apple-m1-python-pandas-and-pipenv-1cab199287c4